# ShouldaMatchers validate_uniquess_of scoped to multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, shoulda, shoulda-matchers

I have a model with a unique index at the db level and model validation checking for uniqueness scoped to multiple columns.

```
# db level
add_index :table1, %i[fk_belongs_to_id col1 col2 col3 col4], unique: true

# model level
validates :fk_belongs_to_id, uniqueness: { scope: %i[col1 col2 col3 col4], case_sensitive: false }
```

In the spec I have:

`it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:fk_belongs_to_id).scoped_to(%i[col1 col2 col3 col4).ignoring_case_sensitivity }`

But I keep getting this error:

```
    NoMethodError:
       undefined method `all' for Symbol:Class
```

How can I test for uniqueness scope with multiple columns?

I am unable to find anything that can help with this in their docs or anything. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solved your own problem, which is awesome, but just a quick note of explanation for future readers:

`it { should ... }` (and the alternative `it { is_expected.to ... }`) translate under the covers to `expect(subject).to ...`. So, both assume that prior to that the current context has defined `subject`.

The other thing to note is that, while RSpec continues to support both `should` and `expect` syntax, the general guidance is to stick with `expect`. In your case it doesn't matter as much since the `should` translates directly to `expect`, but in the more general usage `expect` solves a couple of problems with the older syntax. Check out this [summary](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md) from RSpec about why.

Comment: Ya, I was following the shoulda matchers doc in regards to using should. But I love your explanation :D

Answer (score 1):

It turned out being that I needed to define a `subject` in the spec. I had only seed the error that related to this as `reflect_on_assocation`.

So for clarification, I just added

`subject { Model.new }` and it worked :P